# How can I create a temporary column as the result of arithmetic from two other columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I want to achieve the following:

```
select a, 
       b,
       diff as (b-a)
from some_table;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax isn't far off, try this:

```
select a, 
       b,
       b - a as diff
from some_table;
```

The general ANSI syntax for aliasing a column is:

```
select <expression involving columns> as <alias name>
from some_table
```

Answer (score -1):

select a,b,a-b as diff from some_table;

Comment: This question already have exact answer that you have posted.